# Extending the LoggingFacility in Castle Windsor

Tags: .net, vb.net, castle-windsor, castle

I'm currently using the log4net portion of the Castle Windsor logging facility, like so:

```
objContainer.AddFacility("logging", New LoggingFacility(LoggerImplementation.Log4net)WithConfig("Configs\Log4net.config"))
```

I need to pass in a couple of variables to the logger because I am using dynamic log file names. I have looked at the source code and determined that one possible course of action is to create a custom factory and facility but this is alot of work and I'm not sure it is best practice.

I note Castle has an ExtendedLog4Net version but there seems to be little documentation on it. Can anyone shed any light on the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Ross.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "dynamic log file names"? Can you not configure this in log4net.config? How is the logging facility related? An example or failing test would be best.

Comment: The application I am writing uses the .NET WMI framework. The presentation layer exposes many different WMI classes (providers). Windows creates an object for each one of these in memory (in the same thread). They are all effectively a root object - as a result they all inherit from a base class which in turn does a Resolve() operation to find the service which implements them. I want a log file for each of them. I cannot use filtering because I will end up with a log file for each of the classes resolved underneath and I cannot pass a property to log4net because they share the same thread.

Comment: can you add that to the question, maybe also include an example or failing test?

Comment: I'm using ExtendedLog4Net, but am upgrading libraries and wanting to use the fluent registration .UseLog4Net(). I'm in the same situation as you, in that if I use the fluent version, I don't know what I'll be missing. I cannot see what "extended" offers me that I'll miss when I implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the CreateChildLogger() method to create the loggers needed as I had time constraints on this project. Thanks for all of the advice.